# 2/3 log x = log 4.So in the equation,I just divide 4 and 2/3 and i get 6. So the remaining equation is log x = log 6. Do I just cancel the log?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I forgot about the log rules. Can someone help me by explaining it. And if we need to find the approximate value of f(x) increases from 12.0 to 12.4. Do I need to use the two value so I will get two answer. the f(x) = 3x^2/3

Comment: Because $\log(x)$ is injective, you are indeed allowed to "cancel" the logs.

Comment: $\frac23 \times (log 6) \neq log(\frac23 \times 6)$

Comment: So I can cancel the log because it has the same base right? So the answer will be 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two important properties of logarithms:

\begin{align*} \color{blue}{1)}& \qquad  a\log(x) = \log(x^{a})\\
\color{blue}{2)}& \qquad a^{\log_a(b)} = b
\end{align*}

---

In your problem, you apply them as follows
\begin{align*}
&\frac{2}{3} \log(x) = \log(4) \\
\implies \quad&\log(x)  = \frac{3}{2} \log(4)\\
\overset{\color{blue}{1)}}{\implies} \quad&\log(x)  =  \log\left(4^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)
\end{align*}
Now, assuming that by $\log(x)$ you mean $\log_e(x)$ we get
\begin{align*}
&\log(x)  =  \log\left(4^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\\
\implies \quad& e^{\log_e(x)} = e^{\log_e\left(4^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)} \\
\overset{\color{blue}{2)}}{\implies} \quad& x = 4^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
\implies \quad& x = \sqrt{4^3}\\
\implies \quad & x = \sqrt{64} = \boxed{8}
\end{align*}

---

Indeed, if we have any two logarithms of *the same base* being equated, as was pointed out in the comments we are allowed to cancel out the logarithms because the logarithm function is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), and hence has an inverse function in the exponential.